# Reading file from resource - path must exist: /app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/features/

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I need the classpath of a file. I found this way to get the path using classpath

```
String filePath = com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(feature).getFile();
```

I deployed my app on my server. Executing my code with cucumber I got this error.

```
path must exist: /app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/features/attachment/heal.feature
```

I checked the `app.jar` inside `target` folder and I am not enable to extract and see the content

I am using `pring boot 2` and this is the `pom`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pmc.aop.core</groupId>
<artifactId>pmc-integration-tests</artifactId>
<version>0.1.5-${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <drools.version>7.35.0.Final</drools.version>
    <kie.version>7.35.0.Final</kie.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.22</lombok.version>
    <cucumber-version>5.7.0</cucumber-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pnc.aop.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>aop-lib-kafka-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>

    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>

                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>
```

looks like jar is corrupt

Comment: You _do not use `File`_ to get classpath resources. In Spring, you can simply inject a `Resource` or even an `InputStream` object directly, and the framework will take care of resolving and wiring up the resource for you.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- any example?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources

Comment: Use ``resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + feature).getURI().getPath()`` for ``"features/local/notify.feature"`` and its works with cucumber. But on my server I got ``[null]`` I guess is not getting the file inside the ``jar`` @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: You're trying to turn it into a `File` again; this does not work within jars. Use the `InputStream` directly for resources, always.

Comment: I gotta you but I can not pass ``InputStream`` into ``io.cucumber.core.cli.Main-public static byte run(String[] argv, ClassLoader classLoader) ``. I am triying to execute ``Main.run(new String[]{"--glue", "pmc.aop.integration", file}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())``. File is the resource that I want to find on ``jar`` @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need the classpath of a file. I found this way to get the path using classpath
>
> ```
> String filePath = >com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource(feature).getFile();
> ```
>
> I deployed my app on my server. Executing my code with cucumber I got this error.
>
> ```
> path must exist: /app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/features/attachment/heal.feature
> ```

The file path is not the same as the classpath. If you look at the [spring executable jar format](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html) you'll see a layout that is different from a regular jar file:

```
example.jar
 |
 +-META-INF
 |  +-MANIFEST.MF
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader
 |           +-<spring boot loader classes>
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    |  +-mycompany
    |     +-project
    |        +-YourClasses.class
    +-lib
       +-dependency1.jar
       +-dependency2.jar
```

The contents of `BOOT-INF/classes` and `BOOT-INF/lib` **are on the classpath.** So you can use `classpath:features/attachment/heal.feature` as your feature path.

Do note that Cucumber only has [limited support for scanning spring jar files](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1821).